# How to set an SQLite database as datasource in Dashcode?

Tags: sqlite, dashcode

is it possible to set an SQLite Database as datasource in Dashcode? And how? I'm referring to the "Mobile Safari Web Application Tutorial" (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/MakingaWebApp/MakingaWebApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004692-CH18-SW1). I'd like to replace the static JSON in this tutorial by an SQL query result.

Thank you!

R0byn